# Determine if specific folder is a Recycle Bin from a network share

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I'm following [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/18/8956382.aspx) that shows how to tell if a specific folder is a Recycle Bin. Here's my own version of it:

```
LPITEMIDLIST pidl = NULL;

if (SUCCEEDED(hr = SHParseDisplayName(pFolderPath, NULL, &pidl, 0, NULL)))
{
    IShellFolder *psf = NULL;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlChild;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr = SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&psf, &pidlChild))) 
    {
        SHDESCRIPTIONID did = {0};
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr = SHGetDataFromIDList(psf, pidlChild, SHGDFIL_DESCRIPTIONID, &did, sizeof(did))))
        {
            if(did.clsid == CLSID_RecycleBin)
            {
                _tprintf(L"Folder is the Recycle Bin!\n");
            }
        }

        psf->Release();
    }
}

if(pidl)
{
    CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
    pidl = NULL;
}
```

The code works for local Recycle Bins, but in case of a recycle bin for a folder redirected to a network share (like My Documents, for instance), where the path on the server becomes something like this: `\\SRVR-A\Home\UserName\Documents\$RECYCLE.BIN` the method above does not work, i.e. `did.clsid` is 0 and `did.dwDescriptionId` is `SHDID_FS_DIRECTORY` like it would be for a regular folder.